# Start batch file from specific line

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

How can I start a batch file from a specific line? Is there any way?

my `batch-file`

```
:start
vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 1\test 1.vmx"
vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 2\test 2.vmx"
vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 3\test 3.vmx"
goto start
```

For example, I want to start the `batch-file` from the 3-rd line.

Sorry,
I will try to clarify. I have 3 commands in my file

```
   vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 1\test 1.vmx"
   vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 2\test 2.vmx"
   vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 3\test 3.vmx"
```

When I want to start this batch from `G:\Virtual Machines\test 2\test 2.vmx`, the script is starting, but skipping some commands. I want to start my batch file, for example from the 3-rd line. I tried to write in cli a `file.bat 3`, but it's not working. Whatever it's starting from the first line.

Answer (score 4):

You were not clear on the conditions, so I am showing you an approach which you can amend as you please.

The following is conditional, it depends on the standard input you feed to the batch file. The options you have are:

Run only VMX1

```
batch_file.cmd 1
```

Run only VMX2

```
batch_file.cmd 2
```

Run only VMX3

```
batch_file.cmd 3
```

Run all VMX's once

```
batch_file.cmd all
```

Run all VMX's in a permanent loop (Not sure why you'd want that though)

```
batch_file.cmd all loop
```

And then we have the code. It is really simple. It just evaluates `%1` in most cases, which will determine where your batch-file will start. `%2` is only evaluated once, at the end of the script, in this case to loop if required.

```
@echo off
goto vmx%~1
:start
:vmxall
:vmx1
echo vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 1\test 1.vmx"
if /i not "%~1" == "all" exit /b
:vmx2
echo vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 2\test 2.vmx"
if /i not "%~1" == "all" exit /b
:vmx3
echo vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 3\test 3.vmx"
if /i not "%~1" == "all" exit /b
if /i "%~1" == "all" if /i "%~2" == "loop" goto :start
exit /b
:vmx
echo You did not supply any arguments & pause
```

Comment: Sorry,
I will try to clarify. I have 3 commands in my file`

  vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 1\test 1.vmx"
  vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 2\test 2.vmx"
  vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 3\test 3.vmx"

When I want to start this batch from "G:\Virtual Machines\test 2\test 2.vmx", the script is starting, but skipping some commands. I want to start my batch, for example from the 3-rd line. I tried to write in cmd a "file.bat 3", but it is not working. Whatever it is starting from the first line

Comment: Ok so you were shown ways to start anywhere you want, so what is the issue you have?

Comment: Ok. In my file, I run 3 VMs. I want to run batch starting from "test 2.vmx". My original file has many lines. It is for example..

Answer (score 2):

Lables in batch files can do the trick you are looking for.

You can try this one, in case you want the code is executed only for the third `vmrun` command:

```
goto open
:start
vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 1\test 1.vmx"
vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 2\test 2.vmx"
:open
vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 3\test 3.vmx"
exit /b
goto start
```

Or you can also try this, in case you want the code is executed for the third `vmrun` command and then for the remaining two vmx's:

```
goto open
:start
vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 1\test 1.vmx"
vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 2\test 2.vmx"
exit /b
:open
vmrun -T ws -gu "User" -gp "1" start "G:\Virtual Machines\test 3\test 3.vmx"
goto start
```

Comment: There's one problem though. you'll start at `open` but soon after, it meets `goto start` which will run all 3 vmx's and will run `vmx3` again. I understand you just want to show the concept of labels, but you get my point `:)`

Comment: Well, since the question wasn't clear I tried something, anyway I upvoted your answer because it's more accurate

Comment: You can fix yours by simply putting `exit /b` before `goto start`

Comment: and maybe create another code block. as second option, but do not add `exit /b` before `goto start` but add it before `:open` So if it runs it will start at open, run vmx 3, goto start and only run vmx1 and vmx 2. OP then has both choices available.

Comment: All has been implemented now